# Submit a variable sized (from 0 up to 10) list of integers to server?

Tags: javascript, html

What would be the best way to submit a variable sized (from 0 up to 10) list of integers from client to server?

I was thinking of submitting it via hidden inputs but since the size is variable, I can't assume a safe and good limit? Are there any better ways?

Comment: I would use a concatenated string to pass the list of integers when its variable sized.

Answer (score 1):

Put a delimited list in a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" value="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10" />
```

If the values are in a JavaScript array (mentioning this because you tagged JS), you could do something like this:

```
function CallMeOnSubmit()
{
    var myInts = new Array();
    myInts[0] = 1;
    myInts[1] = 2;

    //Calling .toString() on a JS array will give you a comma delimted list
    document.getElementById("myHiddenInput").value = myInts.toString();
}

<input type="hidden" id="myHiddenInput" value="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

create a javascript object with your desired variables, then JSON encode it and send to server - where you can JSON decode it into a native object of whatever language you use on the server side...

---

Here is a full self contained example using JavaScript (and the jQuery library) on the client side, and PHP on the server side... you can save it into a file called `something.php` and run it from the server. It should serve as a general solution for almost all situations where you need to send data from client side to server side.

```
<?php
if($d = $_POST['d']){ // if data is sent via POST
    // decode the data into a PHP object
    $a = json_decode($d);
    // output the structure of the populated variable
    print_r($a);
    // exit - preventing further output
    exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Quick ajax using jQuery demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    // can be simple array
    // var myData = [1,2,3,4,5]
    // or complex data structure
    var myData = {a:'a thing', b:'more stuff', c:[1,2,3,"That's how easy"]}

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:'.',
        data:{ d: JSON.stringify(myData) },
        success:function(d){ alert(d) }
    })

});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Nothing to see here...
</body>
</html>
```

---

EDIT: add method to include all form data

Here is a self contained example showing how you could serialize all the form data into an array, then add to it with more custom data, and send it via AJAX to the server.

```
<?php
if($d = $_POST['d']){ // if data is sent via POST
    // decode the data into a PHP object
    $a = json_decode($d);
    // output the structure of the populated variable
    print_r($a);
    // exit - preventing further output
    exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Quick ajax using jQuery demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    $('form').submit(function(){


        // get all the form data into an array object
        var allData = $('form').serializeArray()

        // add whatever other data you want, in whatever structure you want
        allData.push({
            name:'myData',
            value: {a:'a thing', b:'more stuff', c:[1,2,3,"That's how easy"] }
        })

        // make AJAX post
        $.post('.',
            {d: JSON.stringify(allData)}, // send all the data as JSON string
            function(i){ alert(i) } // use callback to display server output
        )

        // prevent form from submitting in the normal manner
        return false

    })

});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action='.' method='post'>
        <input type='text' name='fullname'>
        <input type='text' name='comment'>
        <input type='submit'>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you think JSON could be considered overkill for a simple list of integers? You're also assuming that the OP wants to use AJAX, jQuery, and PHP.

Comment: He asked for the __best way__ and I believe this general solution is, because it can scale to any data patterns he requires. He is concerned about the size of the array changing, and the method I propose liberates him from those concerns, so that the client side and server side data patterns match exactly, and can be handled in a similar way. I feel my general solution is simple enough to use in any circumstance, and complex enough to cover most circumstances. He already has __a way__ but was looking to improve his method - I think that is what I have provided.

Comment: While I respect your attempt, I think this is an overly complicated solution that uses two technologies that weren't even mentioned in the OP. How do you know that the site in question is on a server that supports PHP? If the poster is not familiar with jQuery, are you suggesting that they begin to use it just to solve this problem?

Comment: you might be right - but I still think my general solution solves this problem, and maybe other problems too. As for PHP, I had to use something to demo the concept, and can be translated easily - it is only a few lines. As for AJAX, JSON and jQuery, I think it is probably a good idea to learn them, they are all fairly simple if you know javascript - because they are all actually javascript... and the question is tagged as javascript. You can't please all the people all the time, but I had fun writing my self contained demo that passes any data structure from client to server as native object.

Comment: Thank you both. I am already using query & js but I need to submit it along with other data in the form. It is a part of the form.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're sending it but you probably want JSON. This means you build up an array of the integers, convert them to a string when transferring, and decode it back to an array at the server.

In JavaScript:

```
var dataToSend = JSON.stringify([123, 456, 10]);
```

And on the server side you decode it into an object, depending on your server-side language. Most languages have JSON support built in, e.g. for PHP:

```
$receivedArray = json_decode($_GET['dataToSend']);
// if you called the URL parameter as such
```

Answer (score 0):

you can join them in a string by a separator (like - or ;) and post them to server, in server-side split them by code (your server-side lang) and convert each to an integer:

```
var result = "";
result+= val + "-"; // val is an integer
```